# How to attach a date field from another entity to a new form

Tags: 7, entities

I am attaching a few fields from the user entity to a custom form with the following:

```
$account = user_load($user->uid);
foreach ($fields_to_collect as $field) {
  field_attach_form('user', $account, $form, $form_state, NULL, [
    'field_name' => $field
  ]);
}
```

This works fine *except* for date fields (I am using the date_popup widget but I haven't yet narrowed that down as responsible).  Attaching a date field results in the following error: `Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in date_limit_format() (line 2262 of sites/all/modules/date/date_api/date_api.module).`  The date field is just shown as a text field with the text `Format` shown as a description.

The error is due to `$granularity` being `NULL`.  On, for example, the user account edit page which has this field, `$granularity` is something like:

```
[
  'month',
  'day',
  'year'
]
```

Thanks for any help/suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Unsurprisingly, it was my error.

Further up in my function I was building `$form_state` with `form_state_defaults()`.  Once I provided a proper `form_state` everything worked as expected.

Comment: In my case, I forgot to pass $form_state as a reference in the form function definition -- &$form_state solved the error